# Flex 4 - Ant Invalid Embed directive in stylesheet - can't resolve source 'Embed(source="")'

Tags: apache-flex, ant

I am trying to use ant to build my flex project but got an error:

```
Invalid Embed directive in stylesheet - can't resolve source 'Embed(source="/assets/fileNm.jpg")' (File: style.css)
```

I don't know how to do.
Please help me.

```
src
  assets
    css
      style.css
    img
  com
```

My ANT Task:

```
<!-- Complie source-->
<target name="compileBLP" depends="copyAssets">
    <record name="${LOG_FILE}" action="start" append="false" />
    <mxmlc file="${SRC_DIR}/Main.mxml" output="${DEPLOY_DIR}/main.swf">
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
        <compiler.debug>false</compiler.debug>

        <runtime-shared-library-path
            path-element="${FLEX_FRAMEWORK}/framework.swc">
            <url rsl-url="framework_4.1.0.16076.swf"/>
            <url rsl-url="framework_4.1.0.16076.swz"/>
            <url rsl-url="osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swf"/>
            <url rsl-url="osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz"/>
            <url rsl-url="rpc_4.1.0.16076.swf"/>
            <url rsl-url="rpc_4.1.0.16076.swz"/>
            <url rsl-url="spark_4.1.0.16076.swf"/>
            <url rsl-url="spark_4.1.0.16076.swz"/>
            <url rsl-url="sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swf"/>
            <url rsl-url="sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swz"/>
            <url rsl-url="textLayout_1.1.0.604.swf"/>
            <url rsl-url="textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz"/>
        </runtime-shared-library-path>  

        <compiler.source-path path-element="${SRC_DIR}" />
        <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
            <include name="libs" />
        </compiler.library-path>
        <compiler.library-path dir="${basedir}" append="true">
            <include name="libs" />
        </compiler.library-path>
    </mxmlc>
    <record name="${LOG_FILE}" action="stop"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex has always been a bit obtuse with it's relative vs. absolute pathing, add in Maven or ANT and it just compounds the issue. From what I can tell here - you have the assets folder under src and the src listed as a compiler source path, but your embed directive is claiming that it should find it at /assets.

You can do one of the following:

1. Update the embed directive to /src/assets/img...
2. Change the embed directive to relative: ../assets/img
3. Add the assets folder as a compiler source path (but this shouldn't be nested under src then)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.
So 3 solutions which you gave me. They didn't work. :(

There are some "mxml" file got the same error.

I used: [Bindable][Embed(source='assets/icons/setting1.png')]
   private var icon1:Class;
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do many ways and I found the solution for this question.

```
Use: Embed('/assets/img/fileNm.jpg')
Don't use: Embed(source='/assets/img/fileNm.jpg')
```